# Not able to display long text string in status-area of a window created in Progress 4GL

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

It seems like we can not display long text strings in status-area of a window.
I want to display text string long enough to cover complete screen in status-area of window.

Is there any simple way or using windows API's?

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using STATUS DEFAULT or STATUS INPUT statement. The documentation says that the string is limited to 63 characters. This seems like a legacy from the TTY times where parts of the status bar might have been used to indicate key states etc..

I guess you'll have to build your own status bar (turning off the default status bar using STATUS-AREA attribute). Or use an Active X or .NET Control instead.

I'd prefer the use of a .NET Control.

Answer (score 0):

As for me I just use a disabled fill-in at the bottom of the window, with the resize magic (if needed) and a simple API to display text within.